# How do I return a value to a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, return-value

I have to print a table of how far an object will go based on release velocity and angle using a 2D array. Below is the method used to determine the distance then converts it to feet. However, I cannot use a return statement to assign it to its proper place because of the "incompatible types" `error: converting a double [][] to double []`. How would I return the value to the array?

```
public double [] calcDistance()
{
    double [][] total ={ {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}  };

    for (int j = 0;  j < velocity.length; j++)
    {  
        for (int i = 0; i < degrees.length; i++)
      {
         total[j][i] = (Math.pow((velocity[j]*.447), 2) * Math.sin( 2 * Math.toRadians(degrees[i])) / 9.8);
         total[j][i] = total[j][i] * 3.28084;
      }
    }
    return total;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just define the method to return a two dimensional array:

```
public double[][] calcDistance() {
    // Rest of your code...
```

Comment: Got it, once I did that and changed the printf and the method declaration, everything worked smoothly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can only return an object, that is the same type as the method.
So you just have to change the method to
    `public double [][] calcDistance()`